pdfkit support for full utf-8 characters and special chars (arabic, korean, chinese etc)
For our application we have to support a wide range of utf-8 characters, like for arabic, korean or chinese language. Unfortunately, it does not work.
You can even reproduce it in the live demo of the current version. Just paste these sample korean letters to the source code view and check the broken result:

ㄱ ㄴ ㄷ ㄹ ㅁ ㅂ ㅅ ㅇ ㅈ ㅊ ㅋ ㅌ ㅍ ㅎㅏ ㅑ ㅓ ㅕ ㅗ ㅛ ㅜ ㅠ ㅡ ㅣ

https://pdfkit.org/demo/browser.html

I tried to google a lot, most common idea is to change the font to a font with a wider set of characters. I tried all of the standard fonts, provided by pdfkit, but the problem still occurs.
Any ideas?

There is not a single built-in font, that supports utf8. All the provided fonts have WinANSI Encoding only.
Source: https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit/issues/262
An idea is to use Open Sans, it's free and supports most characters: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans
If you use pdfkit standalone in your browser client-sided, an error occurs. A solution is, to base64 encode the font file and pass it as ArrayBuffer:
 const base64ToArrayBuffer = function(base64) {
        var binaryString = atob(base64);
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryString.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < binaryString.length; i++) {
            bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return bytes.buffer;
    };


    document.registerFont('OpenSans_Condensed-Medium', base64ToArrayBuffer(FONT_AS_BASE64_STRING))
    document.font('OpenSans_Condensed-Medium');

Thanks to Jahongir Rahmonov for the base64ToArrayBuffer function
